continue on a saved map in slam_toolbox
I am trying to use slam_toolbox in order to perform slam in a previous saved map. I have created a map using slam toolbox which i have then saved. In the mapper_params_online_async.py file i the try to load the map as shown bellow:
slam_toolbox:
ros__parameters:
# Plugin params
solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
ceres_loss_function: None

# ROS Parameters
odom_frame: odom
map_frame: map
base_frame: base_footprint
scan_topic: /scan
use_map_saver: true
mode: localization

# if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
# or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
# will use pose
map_file_name: my_map_slam
map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
# map_start_at_dock: true

debug_logging: false
throttle_scans: 1
transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
map_update_interval: 5.0
resolution: 0.05
max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
minimum_time_interval: 0.5
transform_timeout: 0.2
tf_buffer_duration: 30.
stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
enable_interactive_mode: true

# General Parameters
use_scan_matching: true
use_scan_barycenter: true
minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
scan_buffer_size: 50
scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
do_loop_closing: true 
loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10
loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

# Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

# Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

# Scan Matcher Parameters
distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
use_response_expansion: true

where i believed this line would initialize a saved map:
 # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
 # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
  # will use pose
 map_file_name: my_map_slam
 map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 # map_start_at_dock: true 

Anyone has an idea of what i am doing wrong. If i need to provide further information let me know.

What is the error?

One thing I had difficulty with is making sure nav2 was actually using the parameter file I was passing on the command line when using the officially installed bringup.
https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/issues/3970
Which ROS 2?  Humble, Jazzy?
Are you using the stock nav2_bringup and navigation_launch.py, or a local overlay?
What is your launch command?
